# Posix Threads - Threads in Parallel

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

```
int total = 200; // total is a global variable

void process()
{
    int local;
    for( int i = 0 ; i< 100 ; i++ ) 
    {
         local = total;
         local--;
         total = local;
    }
}
```

If 2 threads invoke `process()` in parallel, what will be the maximum & minimum value of **total** after both threads finish processing?

i think the minimum value will be 0 but im not sure. maximum value ?? 199 ?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: In C++11 this is undefined behavior due to the race condition on `total`. I'm not sure about C11 though.

Comment: @Mysticial 'undefined behavior' is not always an answer :-P I think OP was looking for an idea of what might happen at the low level. if you check the assembly it just reads total into a register, then writes it back.

Comment: no it is a test review question.

Answer (score 1):

In C11 this is defined as "undefined behavior," which means that it gives no guarantees about it.

This is more or less true of C99 also, although C99 was not written with concurrency in mind. Each thread is ignorant of the other.

Each thread will look at the global variable 'total' 100 times.

However, each thread gets its own local copy, decrements that, and writes it back to the global variable, total.

However, the thread may take the global variable 'total' and keep a temporary copy, without writing it back until the function ends. In this case the lower bound might be 100.

If they don't keep local copies, total may go down by no more than 1, as they both grab total in synchrony, decrement their local copy, and write back.

Without some way of synchronizing the threads, so that one "grabs" total, modifies it, then "releases" it while the other waits, there's no guarentee it'll reach 0.

Mutexes, semaphores, etc. are ways to syncrhonize access across threads.

Pseudo-code:

```
process() {
  for (loop) {
    grab_mutex(total);  // Will wait till total is free
    total--;
    release_mutex(total);
  }
}
```

However, the lower bound is definitely 0; there are no more than 200 opportunities for a decrement.

Comment: We have not yet learned about synchronization of threads using semaphores. The question is " What is the maximum possible value, and minimum possible value of total after the two threads have executed ? "

Comment: I understand the lower bound will be 0. but how can i find out the highest possible value total might have after thread execution?  ( the threads execute in parallel). I think my professor is not expecting a guarantee that total will reach the maximum or minimum value, rather he just wants to know what values are possible.

Comment: @DaffyDaffy it can't be under 0, because there are no more than 200 chances for total to be decremented. for the same reason, it can't be over 200: since only decrements are done, it would need an underflow to be over 200. the exact upper limit is harder to establish though, as it is environment-dependent, but let's say 200 because the behavior is undefined

Comment: @DaffyDaffy and by the way, if your professor says it's 100, that's almost definitely because the local functions are storing temporary copies of the global variable, and then writing them back at the end, and your prof. may not know about that kind of behavior

Comment: While C99 might be mostly silent on the topic of concurrent access to memory, POSIX isn't: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11

Comment: @MichaelBurr indeed, POSIX does provide helpful functions, pthreads.  note at the bottom, "Applications may allow more than one thread of control to read a memory location simultaneously." in the same memory model allows them to write them; POSIX says not to do it, not that it can't be done. and anyhow, the question wasn't about how to fix it - I discussed ramifications of doing this and suggested mutexes, nothing more to do

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave: I wasn't trying to contradict anything in your answer, just pointing out that POSIX imposes requirements about concurrent access to data even if C99 doesn't talk about it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr sorry if I sounded harsh

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave: no problem - didn't sound harsh at all.